# PowerShell: Invoke-Parallel throwing error with "start-process"

Tags: shell, powershell, parallel-processing, server

I'm using the Invoke-Parallel CmdLet that can be [found at the link here](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/Invoke-Parallel).  When I have some dummy code in my script block, it works correctly, but when I add a start-process... command it fails with an error saying

```
Get-RunspaceData : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system    
cannot find the file specified.
At c:\crm\Interfaces\Batches\Invoke-Parallel.ps1:592 char:13
```

My script block looks like so.  Long story short, I'm feeding file names into a block, and I am telling a 3rd party application to use that file as an input for a process.  When the start-process line is removed, it works, with it, it fails.

```
$childFiles| Invoke-Parallel -ImportVariables {
    $importformat = '-f ' + '"CU Imp P19 FI"'
    $importfile = '-d ' + $_ + " " + $user + " " + $pass        
    Write-Host $importformat + " " + $_
    start-process .\mmim.exe -ArgumentList  $user, $pass, '-l:1', 
    $importformat, $importfile -Wait -NoNewWindow
    return "blah"
}
```

Does anyone have any idea of what might be going on?  My PowerShell version is the following

Major:5

Minor:0

Build: 10586

Revision: 117

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Each PowerShell runspace have its own current location. Does `Invoke-Parallel` cares about making current location of spawned runspaces to match current location of main runspace? Will relative path `.\mmim.exe` be resolved correctly, if answer to previous question is *no*?

Comment: @PetSerAl I'll jump on this as soon as I get to something resembling a stable internet connection.

Comment: @PetSerAl Your response was the solution Pet.  If you want, you can post your post as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each PowerShell runspace have its own current location. If `Invoke-Parallel` does not change current location of spawned runspaces to match current location of main runspace, then relative path `.\mmim.exe` may be resolved to entire different executable or not resolved at all and produce given error.